# What's the precedence of comma operator inside conditional operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, comma-operator

What's happening here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x=0,y=0;
    true? ++x, ++y : --x, --y; 
    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
    cout << "y: " << y << endl; //why does y=0 here?

    x=0,y=0;
    false ? ++x, ++y : --x, --y; 
    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
    cout << "y: " << y << endl;
}

x: 1
y: 0

x: -1
y: -1
```

The second case seems fine. I would expect both x and y to increment to 1 in the first case but only the left hand operand increments.

Comment: Please provide code that actually compiles - otherwise I cannot be bothered to help you

Comment: `++y` does happen, but then `--y` does. `true? ++x, ++y : --x, --y` is parsed as `(true ? ++x, ++y : --x), --y`

Comment: @AdrianCornish This code compiles; did you try it?

Comment: @chrisaycock actually it doesn't. Maybe it does if you add `#include <iostream>` and `using std::cout; using std::endl;`

Comment: Yes.  The OP should read sscce.org, but still this is above average in terms of clarity and detail.

Comment: @chrisaycock It does not - and I know why - but that is up to you to fix

Comment: In a question with code that uses `cout`, `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` are just noise.  If that's all that is missing, and the reader can't figure out how to get it to compile, s/he has no business answering C++ questions.

Comment: The same question was asked in _C++ Primer_ Exercise 4.33 (5th Edition).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first one is equivalent to:

```
(true  ? (++x, ++y) : (--x)), --y;
```

The second one is equivalent to:

```
(false ? (++x, ++y) : (--x)), --y;
```

Thus the `--y` is always executed.  In the first line, the increments are executed first so `x = 1, y = 0` is expected.  In the second line, the decrement of `x` is executed first so `x = -1, y = -1` is expected.

---

As noted in a comment (to another answer) by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar):

> And in case anyone is wondering why the comma between `++x` and `++y` doesn't have the same effect, it's because `(true? ++x)` would not be valid at all. So the compiler keeps scanning until it finds the `:`, but beyond that it stops when it reaches a lower precedence operator *[(`,` in this example) or the end of statement]*.

Comment: To state your final paragraph more precisely: precedence (and associativity) of operators only affects binding of the operands at the left and right of the operator, not the one in the middle. Of course the ternary operator is the only one to have a middle operand at all in the first place. But along these lines one might consider a pair of parentheses as a unary (identity) operator whose single operand is in the middle (between the "operator symbols"), which would explain why the grouping it achieves is unaffected by any precedence rules.

Answer (score 4):

The `y` is zero because comma has [the lowest precedence among all C++ operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Because its precedence is lower than that of the ternary conditional operator, the conditional operators are parsed as `true? ++x, ++y : --x` and `false? ++x, ++y : --x`. In both cases, the `--y` statement is executed *unconditionally*.

**EDIT** The first comma is different because the compiler has found a `?`, so now it needs a `:` to complete the "when true" expression of the conditional. That is why both `++x` and `++y` are taken in.

Comment: And in case anyone is wondering why the comma between `++x` and `++y` doesn't have the same effect, it's because `(true? ++x)` would not be valid at all. So it keeps scanning until it finds the `:`, but beyond that it stops when it reaches a lower precedence operator.

Comment: Oh and never do `if(x==100,000)` learnt that the hard way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Read the standard

> §5.18 Comma operator [expr.comma]
>
> ¶1 The comma operator groups left-to-right.
>
> ```
> expression:
> assignment-expression
> expression , assignment-expression
> ```
>
> A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right; the left expression is a discardedvalue
>   expression (Clause 5).<sup>83</sup> Every value computation and side effect associated with the left expression
>   is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the right expression. The type
>   and value of the result are the type and value of the right operand; the result is of the same value category
>   as its right operand, and is a bit-field if its right operand is a glvalue and a bit-field.
>
> ¶2 In contexts where comma is given a special meaning, [ Example: in lists of arguments to functions (5.2.2)
>   and lists of initializers (8.5) —end example ] the comma operator as described in Clause 5 can appear only
>   in parentheses. [ Example:
>
> ```
> f(a, (t=3, t+2), c);
> ```
>
> has three arguments, the second of which has the value 5. —end example ]

Comment: Thanks. true? (++x, ++y) : (--x, --y); fixed. Lesson: always use parenthesis where intent is non trivial.

Comment: @user1626720 - not to mention "don't abuse the ternary operator". The code in question should be written with if ... else, since the value of the ternary operator is discarded.