# lvalue required as left operand of assignment in conditional operator

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors, conditional-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int a = 1, b;
        a ? b = 3 : b = 4;
        printf("%d, %d", a, b);
        return 0;
}

[user@localhost programs]$ gcc -Wall vol.c
vol.c: In function ‘main’:
vol.c:5:16: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
  a ? b = 3 : b = 4;
                ^
```

I have given lvalue as `b` then why `gcc` is showing error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has to do with operator sequencing. What the compiler thinks you're doing is

```
(a ? b = 3 : b) = 4
```

which obviously is incorrect.

Instead, why not put the `b` on the left side, and get only the value to assign using the conditional expression, like

```
b = a ? 3 : 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditional operator (`?:`) always returns a value on the basis of a certain condition becomes true or false. In other words it can be said that `?:` returns always an r-value. And an r-value never be placed on left of an assignment expression. The statement

```
a ? b = 3 : b = 4;
```

is interpreted by compiler as

```
(a ? b = 3 : b) = 4;
```

similar to equating

```
3 = 4;
```

which is wrong.
You are claiming that *I have given lvalue as b*, which is wrong! `b` will bind to `?:` operator and participate in evaluating r-value by the statement

```
 a ? b = 3 : b;
```

and hence you are assigning an r-value (`3`) to an r-value (`4`)!
To use `b` as l-value you can do this by doing

```
b = a ? 3 : 4;
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12136188/2455888) may also help you to understand the binding of operators to the operand `?:`.

Comment: Technically your answer is correct but you misunderstood the OP's question.

Comment: @PP.; OP wants to use `b` as an l-value as he stated in question: ***I have given lvalue as b***

Answer (score -2):

The following compiles:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b;
    a ? ( b = 3 ) : ( b = 4 );
    printf("%d, %d", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I would give you a long story about how failing to explicitly parenthesise your dependencies can cause fatal issues in code. But it's like wearing a seatbelt in a car - a lot of people simply refuse to believe it is worth it until they are in a very messy accident.

Comment: @haccks Why is it useless?

Comment: @haccks - this is what the OP wanted. Or maybe not. The OP never specified that they wanted a change to the variable `a`. In fact how can you assume the OP wanted a result stored in `a`? During declaration `a` was assigned a value and `b` was not, so it is more likely the OP wanted to assign `b` a value, not `a` (which was already assigned). This is a common pattern for short `if .. then .. else` statements. Just because it isn't as common as `b = a ? 3 : 4` doesn't mean it is incorrect and there may be times when the side-effects of this pattern are desirable.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer. I never told that OP wants to change the variable `a`.

Comment: @haccks you don't even understand what the `?:` operator does in my answer! I mean, **come on**. If you don't even understand C how can you possibly imagine you know what the OP wants?

Comment: @haccks now you're trying to vandalise my post? With American spellings? I'm about to report you to the moderators if you persist in this abuse.

Comment: I think you took it personal. I am not here to fight with anyone. I just tried to edit and withdraw my down-vote because I thought I was wrong. Feel free to report if you think that edit was abuse.

Comment: @haccks Since when is replacing English with American anything other than hostility? First you complain that you don't understand C. Now you claim not to understand English. What next?

Comment: I don't know about that. Neither I am American nor English is my native language. My apologies if my edit abused you in someway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35774/discussion-between-pp-and-haccks)